# Spring microservice instance is not registering with Eureka running in port other than 8761

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

application.yml of my microservice (client to Eureka)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: queue1

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true  
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/

server:
  port: 7777

app:
  id: ${random.uuid}
```

application.yml of Eureka

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer1
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
server:
  port: 8762
```

I am starting Eureka in port 8762 and referring to that in my microservices. 
Microservice is failing to register itself with Eureka. 
Following is the exception from microservice logs.

```
2019-03-21 17:02:16.248 ERROR 1804 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ZUUL_RIBBON/ICB8061.ibsplc.com:zuul_ribbon:8080 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1479) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1446) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]



2019-03-21 17:02:16.278 ERROR 1804 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8762/}

javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Root name 'timestamp' does not match expected ('instance') for type [simple type, class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo]
 at [Source: (com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler$HttpClientResponseInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.readFrom(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:110) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:105) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1405) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
```

Now the most important thing is, everything is perfectly fine if I change the Eureka server port and the microservice's Eureka registration port to 8761 !!!! Registration of microservice is succeding in this case.

Did this multiple times before posting the question and it is behaving like this.

Any inputs here would be very much helpful.

Comment: The springboot version that I am using is 2.1.3.RELEASE.                                                     And the cloud version : Greenwich.RELEASE

Comment: I have       

defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

Maybe try defaultZone: http://localhost:8762/eureka ?

Comment: This works! There shoudl be eureka in the defaultZone property. Thanks a lot Marx......

Comment: No make it more clear. defaultZone should be "http://localhost:8762/eureka" and not "http://localhost:8762".   When port 8761 is used and when defaultZone value is "http://localhost:8761" - registration works fine. In this case, I GUESS , internally, eureka uses the url "http://localhost:8761/eureka" instead of what has been given on the property file "http://localhost:8761"

Comment: The /eureka worked for me, but not in all cases. I have a spring boot module version 2.1.5 working fine with  http://localhost:9100 , and another spring boot version 2.1.3 which needs  http://localhost:9100/eureka otherwise throws the same MismatchedInputException error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was due to spring security dependencies in the Eureka server project. After adding the @EnableWebSecurity code to the eureka server application fixed for me.

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
   static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
```

Spring Boot Verison - 2.3.2.RELEASE
Spring Cloud Version - Hoxton.SR1
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2754#issuecomment-372808529